# Delete row and object from tableView when dismissing ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am new to iOS and i have a problem. I have two `UIViewControllers` first one is *ResponsesViewController* (`UITableView`), second one *DetailResponsesViewController*. When i select a row in *ResponsesViewController*, *DetailResponsesViewController* is pushed
. As my backend, i am using parse.com.

*ResponsesViewController* is filled with Parse.com objects, when i select one row, *DetailResponsesViewController* is pushed with object from selected row. I solved this, but i have a backButton in *DetailResponsesViewController*, there is no other way how to dismiss this controller, only when user taps backButton and no other way how to delete objects, only in *DetailResponsesViewController* tapping this backButton. When the button is tapped, i want to delete the object from parse.com, dismiss the controller and delete the object from *ResponsesViewController* (delete row with that object), in the code below, i have some solutions, but it doesn't work properly, it deletes the object from server every time, that works, but it doesn't delete it very time from `UITableView`, for example, i have 10 rows, and every 3rd row isn't deleted and when i pop back to tableView from *DetailResponsesViewController* it is still visible in the tableView but deleted from server, and when i select another VC from menu and come back again, it disappears.

I tried a lot of solutions, putting `[self.tableView reloadData]`, mostly everywhere, but still deletes only sometimes the row from TableView.

It works the same like SnapChat, but without the timer :) when the user reads the message from tableView, is gets deleted.

Does anybody know, where is the problem, or am i using a bad solution? Thanks a lot for help.

My code

ResponsesViewController.h

```
@interface ResponsesViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *responses;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *selectedResponse;

@end
```

ResponsesViewController.m

```
@interface ResponsesViewController ()
@end
@implementation ResponsesViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

//getting the objects from parse.com
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"smajlici"];
    [query whereKey:@"recieverFacebookiD" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"fbId"]];
    [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"current user is %@", error);
        } else {
//adding objects from server into MutableArray
            self.responses = [objects mutableCopy];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];
}


//------------------------------------------

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 69;
}
//------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
//------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.responses count];
}
//------------------------------------------

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"responseCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    PFObject *object      = [self.responses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text   = [object objectForKey:@"senderFbName"];

    return cell;
}
//------------------------------------------

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    self.selectedResponse = [self.responses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailResponse" sender:self];
}
//------------------------------------------

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

//sending object to DetailResponsesVC

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailResponse"]) {
        DetailResponsesViewController *controller = (DetailResponsesViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.selectedResponse               = self.selectedResponse;                                
    }
}


@end
```

DetailResponsesViewController.h

```
@interface DetailResponsesViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *selectedResponse;
- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

DetailResponsesViewController.m

```
@interface DetailResponsesViewController ()
@end
@implementation DetailResponsesViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
}

- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {

    //selectedresponse is an object sent to this viewController using SEGUE
    //from "didselectrowAtIndexPath" ResponsesViewController

    [self.selectedResponse deleteInBackground];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: you can add an custom delegate to reload and delete the data

Comment: I am not sure, but it looks like you are reloading the table from a background thread (findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock) may be you can try to run it in main thread.

Comment: try reload on main thread `[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)
                                 withObject:nil
                              waitUntilDone:NO];`

Comment: @codeIgnitor thats doesn't work, i put it into VCwillappear and VCdidappear.

Comment: @Krrish Parse team says on their website that all "findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock" run on main thread, so i guess, this won't work, but thanks or answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following, it will only get new Parse data when the view is loaded to save constant Parse calls (then add a UIRefreshControl so you can pull to reload the data) and will remove the object before the table is next shown.

ResponsesViewController.m

```
@interface ResponsesViewController ()
@end
@implementation ResponsesViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self loadParseData];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated]
    [self.tableView reloadData];
} 

-(void)loadParseData {
//getting the objects from parse.com
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"smajlici"];
    [query whereKey:@"recieverFacebookiD" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"fbId"]];
    [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"current user is %@", error);
        } else {
//adding objects from server into MutableArray
            self.responses = [objects mutableCopy];
            [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    }];
}


//------------------------------------------

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 69;
}
//------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
//------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.responses count];
}
//------------------------------------------

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"responseCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    PFObject *object      = [self.responses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text   = [object objectForKey:@"senderFbName"];

    return cell;
}
//------------------------------------------

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    self.selectedResponse = [self.responses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.responses removeObject:self.selectedResponse];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailResponse" sender:self];
}
//------------------------------------------

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

//sending object to DetailResponsesVC

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailResponse"]) {
        DetailResponsesViewController *controller = (DetailResponsesViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.selectedResponse               = self.selectedResponse;                                
    }
}


@end
```